# Paperclip uploading file in the wrong directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

So, I'm using paperclip and capistrano.
For some reasons, the files are not being uploaded in `/shared/public/system/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename` but in `/shared/public/system/system/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename`. I don't understand why.
Also when I'm trying to display a picture, the url is `mywebsite.com/system/companies/logos/000/000/015/medium/logo_small.jpg` instead of a pretty url.

here is my model:
company.rb

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :logo, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" },
                     processors: [:compression],
                    :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png",
                    :path => "system/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename",
                    :url => "system/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:basename.:extension" 
  validates_attachment_content_type :logo, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

and my initializer:
paperclip.rb

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin/"
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:storage] = :fog
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:fog_credentials] = {:provider => "Local", :local_root => "#{Rails.root}/public/system"}
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:fog_directory] = ""
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:use_timestamp] = false
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this to,

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:fog_credentials] = {:provider => "Local", :local_root => "#{Rails.root}/public"}
```

You can also try this one, i think there is no need to pass :local_root in paperclip.eb file

```
:path => ":Rails.root/public/system/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename"
```

Comment: any idea why the url aren't 'pretty' ?

Comment: may be that was the problem ,but i have updated my answer because it is working fine in my application.